# Raise/lower a single character of a font (hyphen)

Tags: fonts, typography, hyphenation

**The font I'm using (Merriweather Sans) places the hyphen [a little too high](http://ebensorkin.wordpress.com/2013/12/26/font-hinting-mysterydiscovery/#comment-404):**

[image]

Is there any way I can fix this for the entire document,

in a way that doesn't affect the other fonts?

Test document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{merriweather}
\begin{document}

\sf
h-y-p-h-e-n

% I want the code above to look like:
h\raisebox{-.15ex}{-}y\raisebox{-.15ex}{-}p\raisebox{-.15ex}{-}h\raisebox{-.15ex}{-}e\raisebox{-.15ex}{-}n

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 31 Mar 2014: The Merriweather font has been updated with a lower hyphen.**

Comment: You mean changing also the automatically inserted hyphens?

Comment: @egreg Yes. Any occurrence of the hyphen character, no matter whether it was put there manually or inserted automatically.

Comment: With `pdflatex` the only possibility is to modify the font, I'm afraid.

Comment: @egreg Really? I thought that virtual fonts could perhaps do something (but I have no idea on how to use them). Now, I've been in touch with the font author and it's possible that I can obtain an updated version that fixes this and other issues.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh It could be done with virtual fonts. You can edit the relevant files directly but it would probably be easier to use `fontinst` which provides commands enabling you to control this. Note that it already depends on virtual fonts. There's no reason not to create a distinct set for your own purposes but I'm not clear whether the existing virtual fonts include any tweaks which you might lose out on. (There doesn't seem to be a script or Makefile provided as source, at least in TeX Live. This might mean the commands were run directly without any tweaks - or they were added manually.)

Answer (score 8):

As egreg says, it can't be done in a generalized way.  And in this answer, I don't have merriweather font, so I just demonstrate the technique (and exaggerate the effect) on the standard CM font.

One can locally achieve what you ask by making `-` active;  however, that breaks many, many things, because it means the negative sign has been redefined.  So the compromise I propose here is a macro pair `\newhyphenON` and `\newhyphenOFF`.  In this way, you can turn `\newhyphenON` when you are just typing text with your shifted hyphens, and turn it off for just about everything else.

In this MWE, I show how, when `\nehyphenOFF` has been invoked, the minus sign is restored for use in a `\raisebox`.  But when `\nehyphenON` is invoked, the shifted hyphen is in place.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{merriweather}
\sffamily
\begin{document}
\let\svhyphen-
\def\newhyphen{\raisebox{-.5ex}{\svhyphen}}
\catcode`-\active
\def\newhyphenON{\catcode`-\active\def-{\newhyphen}}
\def\newhyphenOFF{\catcode`-=12\let-\svhyphen}
\catcode`-=12

\newhyphenON
h-y-p-h-e-n

\newhyphenOFF
h-y-p-h-e-n X\raisebox{-1ex}{X}

\newhyphenON
h-y-p-h-e-n

\newhyphenOFF
h-y-p-h-e-n

\end{document}
```

[image]