# Is it possible to type easily polytonic greek in XeTeX?

Tags: unicode, greek

Some years ago, I used polutonikogreek option of the babel package to insert acutes, graves and other symbols in the text. For example, with \textgreek{fu/sis} => φύσις. The problem is that I cannot use \usepackage{fontspec} together with inputenc and babel packages. Is there any "textgreek" alternative command  to insert easily polytonic greek in XeLaTeX (using simple characters like  >, ' ,<,  | etc of polutonicgreek option)?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30832/4427 help?

Comment: @egreg Yes of course! What an excellent solution. The only problem I have: I can not understand your instructions: teckit_compile asciitogreek.map  How I will convert asciitogreek.map and where to put the conversion? I have Windows 7 +TeXLive Thanks!

Comment: Save `asciitogreek.map` in the same directory as your main TeX file and open a command window in the same directory; then you should be able to type `teckit_compile asciitogreek.map` at the prompt and get the required `asciitogreek.tec` file.

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to have a more "portable"  and "configurable" solution? I tried α| with no result. (So I have again to change all the asciitogreek.map for my needs..) I would like something like \usepackage{newunicodechar} (the commands do not work always for  any possible combination of two or more characters) or using active characters as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169093/active-characters-in-linguistics?

Comment: The feature can be accommodated, but it requires some work; basically one has to add for `α` the same combinations as for `a`. Doing `\newunicodechar{α}{a}` would be a temporary workaround, but not really a good one.