# Symbol not in line with text

Tags: symbols, vertical-alignment, fontsize, scaling

I'm using this [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159682/69453) of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159669/how-to-print-a-warning-sign-triangle-with-exclamation-point) for printing a warning sign. But the text and the Symbol are vertically not correct algigned aligned in my special case.

I want to have the same lower baseline for the symbol as for letters like (`a`, `b`, `c`) and not (`q`, `p`, `g`, `y`). The upper baseline is okay for me.

[image: Not so nice veritcally aligned sign]

Comment: There is useful advice here: Raise/lower a single character of a font (hyphen)   http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154613/89098

Comment: Try with this [solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159701/11604)  but instead of `\small` and `\Large`, use  `\tiny` and `\normalsize`,  respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> See edited answer at the end, with a cleaner and adaptative solution

Quick, dirty, and very explicit, but it works :

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \raisebox{0.325ex}{\resizebox{!}{1.2ex}{\danger}} dasdfcsdasda
\end{document}
```

[image]

of course, it need to be adapted according to the font you use...

---

## Explanations:

**1.** Initial state: `\danger dasdfcsdasda`

[image]

**2.** First, we need to reduce the size of the warning sign.

It is achieved through the macro `\resizebox{width}{height}{what is to be resized}` (of the `graphicx` package) where the argument `!` is used to keep proportions the same. As first approximation, we took:

```
\resizebox{!}{1ex}{\danger} dasdfcsdasda
```

[image]

**3.** However, we observe that the `resizebox` keep the resized symbol bottom-aligned with the original one.

We thus need to "raise" is, using `\raisebox{length}{content to be raised}`. As first approximation, we used:

```
\raisebox{0.3ex}{\resizebox{!}{1ex}{\danger}} dasdfcsdasda
```

[image]

**4.** Finally, we fiddled the length in order to get something more correct

---

## Edit

Here is an adaptative solution that assess the lengths according to current context (font family, and size).

```
\documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{graphicx}%                                          to access \settoheight and \settodepth macros

    \usepackage{fourier}%                                           to access \danger icon
    \usepackage{libertine}%                                         set serif font
    \usepackage{roboto}%                                            set sans-serif font (different height)

    \newlength{\myheight}
    \newlength{\mydepth}

    \newcommand{\myDanger}{%
        \settoheight{\myheight}{l}%                                 in order to get the maximal height of letters in the font used
        \settodepth{\mydepth}{\danger}%                             in order to retrieve the actual baseline
        \resizebox{!}{\myheight}{\raisebox{\mydepth}{\danger}}%     seems counterintuitive to me (I'd have resized, then raised... but well, it works, so... !)
    }

\begin{document}
    \myDanger dasdfcsdasda

    {\sffamily \myDanger dasdfcsdasda}

    {\Huge \sffamily \myDanger dasdfcsdasda}

    {\Huge \myDanger  dasdfcsdasda}

    {\Huge\myDanger{\sffamily\myDanger}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've briefly tried to make things cleaner assessing character height and depth using [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275380/64454) and explanations found on [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40977/64454) (e.g. with `\newlength{\myheight}` `\newlength{\myraise}` `\settoheight{\myheight}{d}` `\settodepth{\myraise}{p}` `\raisebox{\myraise}{\resizebox{!}{\myheight}{\danger}} dasdfcsdasda`) but without real success